# extending jade templates and compiling them at client side

Tags: client, extend, pug

I am using jade for templating in my webapp. But i am using it at client side. Hence the whole compilation of the jade template is done on client's machine. But I am not able to use the extend feature of jade template. For some reasons, the jade template can't extend another template, it keeps on giving me errors like "Failed to load path". After debugging i found that it requires jade.js which is already in that directory and all the other dependencies are there in the directory, it still gives the error. Please help me solving this problem